# Embedding ArcMap map (*.mxd) in blog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mxd

I am learning ArcGIS so there is a lot I still need to learn. I created a map in ArcMap and want to insert this map on my blog. Basically, I want to embed it. But all I can find is how to embed a map I make on ArcGIS On Line.

How do I take this map (mxd extension) and put it on my blog?

I did upload it in to my content on line if that is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to embed your map document (.mxd file) on a web page. The reason for this is that the .mxd file is supposed to be used with a desktop application.

1. If you would like to let users of your blog interact with the map layers of the map document, you would need to find alternative ways to share your data such as uploading your data into an ArcGIS Online account and build a webmap which is something you've already done.
2. If you don't need the map to be interactive, you can just export the map document into a static image file such as .jpg or .png using ArcMap.
3. You can also search for other web services that provide publishing of geospatial datasets with its representation (such as https://qgiscloud.com/), but this would most likely require re-building your map since ArcMap map document (.mxd file) is a proprietary file format which can be used only with ArcGIS Desktop applications or applications built using its SDK.

Comment: I thought about an image but do want to keep it interactive. So I may go with your first option. I will work on it today and see how to build it on line. I assume I have to build the map again on line or am I able to use the one I uploaded and work from that in webmap. I appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: If you have ArcGIS Pro, then you can share your map document you author in Pro (not in ArcMap) directly into ArcGIS Online. Otherwise, you would need to publish multiple layers individually and bring them together in a new web map.

Comment: I do not have pro but thinking about getting it. I went ahead and designed it on line. The good thing was that I already had shapefiles created so all I had to do is upload the layers and edit them. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer, so the thread is closed. Thanks!